# C - Check if character is surrounded by quotes

Tags: c, string

Say I have this string: `"this","is a, string"`

I want to be able to check if a comma is inside a pair of quotation marks. The first comma is not, whereas the second comma is. How could I achieve this in C?

Comment: try stack data structure.

Comment: The answer to that question is very elementary programming. After you try something and it doesn't work, you can post the code and explain how it fails.

Comment: @DavidHarris I know for a fact that the strings I am working with have an even amount of quotation marks in them. I was thinking I could go through the string in a for loop. When I find a comma, if there are an odd amount of quotation marks either ahead or behind it, it's contained in quotation marks.

Comment: @MortalMan don't forget to add an answer as accepted if your problem is soved ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would do it is :

1. initialize a boolean variable named like `quotesOpen` to a falsy value
2. go char by char through the string until you find `\0`, and toggle the boolean if the char is `"`
3. when you encounter a comma, check the state of your boolean to know if it is in quotes or not

Comment: Well, I am quite embarrassed by this question to be honest. Thanks!

Comment: @MortalMan, It is a good question, You should try some methods and post your codes. Show your ideas. And that, you can do better.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This way if you want to find `,`in between `" "`**

1 - If first time you found `"` set flag variable to true

2 - Use loop while You get another `"`

and in that loop check whether `,`is present or not

If you found `"` second time then set flag to false

3 - repeate the step 1 and step 2 while you get `NULL` character in the sting

**Try This way if you want to find `,`in outside `" "`**

1 - Set flag to false

2 - Check `,` if present in the string before `"` then `,` is present outside of the `" "`

3 - Repeat above steps till you reach `NULL` character in the string.